# How i can increase a distance btween the rectangle shape in a scene?

Tags: c++, qt

Good Morning every one.
I create a code in QT creator using c++ language,my problem is when I draw a rectangular shapes in scene, this shapes were very close [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgW1a.png).This are the `x{45,45,42,40,35,35,40}` and the `y {68,70,68,66,66,69,69} coordinates`.

When I zoom the distance between the rectangles should not be changed.

this is the part of my code that I have created for drawing the shapes:

```
//steps for draw the store

   QGraphicsScene * scene=new QGraphicsScene();
     QString st=sl[0];//sl it is a liste contains the coordiantes. 
     listDX=st.split(',');
     st=sl[1];
     listDY=st.split(',');
     for(int i=0;i<listDX.length();i++)
     {
         if(listDX[i]!=" " && listDY[i]!=" ")
         {
         QGraphicsRectItem *rect=new QGraphicsRectItem();
         rect->setRect(listDX[i].toInt(),listDY[i].toInt(),20,20);
         QRadialGradient gradient(-3, -3, 10);
         gradient.setCenter(3, 3);
         gradient.setFocalPoint(3, 3);
         gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(Qt::red).light(120));
         gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(Qt::darkRed).light(120));
         rect->setBrush(gradient);
         rect->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 0));
         //add the item to the scene
         scene->addItem(rect);
       }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I did not fully understand this line "*I want when I do a zoom the distance between the rectangles will be occurs provided that the coordinates of the rectangles will be not changed.*"... Do you want it to change only its position, not its size when resized?

Comment: yes, I only want to change its position provided their coordinates do not change.

Comment: Does *coordinate* mean the *size coordinates* here? Because the position **depends** on the coordinates as well...

Comment: for example like a map when you  zoom in ,you can see the distance between objects(building,...) ,but the coordinates of these objects will be not changed.

Comment: Ah, that is a term called [scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry))... Is this what you meant? Here you have to multiply all the coordinates with the scale (zoom factor)...

Comment: Have you tried doing something like: `rect->setRect(listDX[i].toInt() * 3,listDY[i].toInt() * 3,20,20);`... Here 3 is the *distance* which you have mentioned...

Comment: I try to do scene->scale(2,2) but it does n't work.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the position with the distance (your zoom factor) just like I gave above?

Comment: yes,I did but I don't  want to change the coordinate of the rectangle because the problem stay the same.

Comment: I am trying my best to understand what you want here and the best conclusion I can draw here is that you want the rectangular boxes to scatter in different positions and not go in the same direction... ?

Comment: Thanks for your help,i think the best way is to multiply the coordinate same as you told me without doing the zoom.